# Which panel is associated with a particular camera? MEL

Tags: maya, mel

I know you can query which camera is associated with a particular panel. But, is there a way you can do it the other way around?

I want to be able to see what panel is associate with a particular camera.

Example:

> > getPanel -q mainCamera;
> >
> > // modelPanel1

Thanks for the help yall

Comment: Did you meant **camera is associated with a particular panel** instead of **camera is associated with a particular camera** in your first sentence?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This script returns which panels are associated with a particular camera (in this case: persp).

**Mel version:**

```
proc string[] getPanelFromCamera(string $cameraName){
    string $listPanel[];
    for( $panelName in `getPanel -type modelPanel`){
        if( `modelPanel -query -camera $panelName` == $cameraName){
            $listPanel[size($listPanel)] = $panelName;
        }
    }
    return $listPanel;
}

print `getPanelFromCamera("persp")`;
```

**Python version:**

```
import maya.cmds as cmds

def getPanelFromCamera(cameraName):
    listPanel=[]
    for panelName in cmds.getPanel( type="modelPanel" ):
        if cmds.modelPanel( panelName,query=True, camera=True) == cameraName:
            listPanel.append( panelName )
    return listPanel

print getPanelFromCamera("persp")
```

**Note:**
I'm usually don't script in mel, so the mel version of this code is a litteral translation from the python version. I also thought that the Python version might be useful for future readers.

Comment: This works great. Thank you for even deciphering my bad English. Do you know if there is a way to use unique camera names on the "modelPanel -query -camera $panelName." If there are two cameras with the same name it doesn't work. It doesn't work with "|cameraName" either..

Comment: Something strange, if there are two cameras with the same name. (|camName & |group1|camName) then the "modelPanel -query -camera |camName" will accept "|"

Answer (score 0):

If you **have** the panel, and you **want the camera** associated with it, you can simply query it

```
import maya.cmds as cmds
cmds.modelPanel("modelPanel1", query=True, camera=True)
```